# How to monitor a difficult webpage with curl

Tags: javascript, php, web, curl, monitor

I'm trying to monitor [this page](https://otce.finra.org/otce/dailyList?viewType=Symbol%2FName%20Changes) and send an email if it changes. I tried to use curl, but that doesn't work because it seems to be generated on the fly with JavaScript.

Comment: Have you tried  selenium? but @peter comments it's appropriate too.

Comment: your question is too broad. make a question about `how to monitor otce.finra.org`, not `how to monitor a difficult webpage`, that's too broad.

Comment: Thank you for the responses. I would think asking how to monitor the entire site would be a lot broader than how to monitor just one page. All I really want to do is know when it changes (which it does during each day), I don't really care about the actual content.......

Comment: I looked at Selenium. Looks interesting. However, I have a PHP script where I'd like to integrate some CUrl process to check for changes to the page and then send an EMail from that PHP script. This script already parses other web pages no problem. But I can't find what to monitor on the page I posted....z

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to checking this URL instead since this is where that page gets its data:

https://api.finra.org/data/group/otcMarket/name/otcDailyList

When viewing your original page, open your Chrome dev tools and click on the 'network' tab. You'll see a list of requests made to load that page. Look for the request to 'otcDailyList', it has a XHR type. You can then inspect the headers to see the request headers used and the payload to see what the POST payload was. With this info, you can mimic the request using curl.

From what I can see the request payload looks like this:

```
{
    "quoteValues":false,
    "delimiter":"|",
    "limit":100000,
    "sortFields":["-dailyListDatetime","+oldSymbolCode"],
    "dateRangeFilters":[
        {
            "fieldName":"dailyListDatetime",
            "startDate":"2019-04-27 00:00:00",
            "endDate":"2019-04-27 23:59:59"
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm assuming you can adjust that to get the data you need (e.g. adjust the dates).

So in your curl request use the same request headers and post payload to see if you can pull out the correct data.

Have a crack at it and see what you discover.

Comment: That or https://api.finra.org/data/group/otcMarket/name/otcSecurityMaster

Comment: Thank you Peter!! ...I looked at both of those, but they just have old data in them from 2018. This page updates every day at various times.

Comment: It looks like you can add some `Content-type` or `Accept` headers for json and then you can add some query parameters to get other data. You can look at your dev tools network tab to see the Ajax request when the page loads.

Comment: I'm sorry Peter, but I don't know enough about Ajax to be able to do that. That's why I'm asking the community with some help on this.....Thank you.

Comment: Update your question with the complete script and show what is not working.

Comment: Glad to hear you got it sorted out!

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of time on this, and the help of some other programmers, here is the bagged and tagged solution, for anyone else that is looking at array within array request payload data:

```
$RequestPayload = array(
            "quoteValues" => false,
            "delimiter" => "|",
            "limit" => 100000,
            "sortFields" => ["-dailyListDatetime","+oldSymbolCode"],
            "dateRangeFilters" => [array("fieldName"=>"dailyListDatetime","startDate"=>"2019-05-21 00:00:00","endDate"=>"2019-05-21 23:59:59")], 
            );

        $JSONEncoded = json_encode($RequestPayload);
        echo "<P> JSONEncoded: <P><P> $JSONEncoded <P><P>";

        $ReferLink = 'https://Website.com';

        $CurlHandle = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($CurlHandle, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.Website.com");
        curl_setopt($CurlHandle, CURLOPT_REFERER, $ReferLink);
        curl_setopt($CurlHandle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($CurlHandle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('Content-Type: application/json')); 
        curl_setopt($CurlHandle, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($CurlHandle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($CurlHandle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,json_encode($RequestPayload));

        $output = curl_exec($CurlHandle);
        echo "<pre>";
        echo $output;

        die();
```